# How can I use two way bindings with dependency properties?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I read that I need to implement InotifyPropertyChanged but I can't have my control inherit from two different classes.

I'm a little confused as to how I do this.

Basically I wish to have a parent control have a property bound to a control in the UI (already done).

and then I wish to bind that value to a property in a child FrameworkElement.

however, the usercontrol is already inheriting from usercontrol, and multiple inheritance is not supported. How do i go about alerting other dependencyproperties that my dependency property has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is not a class.  It is an interface, and C# allows you to inherit from as many interfaces as you'd like.

If that doesn't clear up your issue, please add more details.  An example would be great.

Comment: can i ask one more simple question. If I'm databinding two dependency properties, shouldn't I not need to implement Inotifypropertychanged? But in my case the target property is not updating when the source property changes even though it's a two way binding.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet: It looks like you'll need to ask another question.  I'm not sure what you mean by "databinding two dependency properties".